# Disable printing extraneous job info when I print a images

Tags: printing

**As of 10/11/12 I this is still a problem. [Peterling](https://askubuntu.com/questions/194225/disable-printing-extraneous-job-info-whenever-i-print-an-image#comment241282_194225), that link you gave me was for Windows. Not Ubuntu. I need to know how to do this in Ubuntu.**

Whenever I print off an image, before the actual image prints, I get these weird "print job" sheets. (I named them that, because I don't know what else to call them.)

They say something like:

```
Media Limits: 0.12 x 0.38 to 8.38 x 10.38 inches
Job ID: Officejet-Pro-L7700-64
Driver: hp-officejet_pro_17700.ppd
Driver version:
Description: HP Officejet Pro L7700
Make and Model: HP Officejet Pro L7700, hpcups 3.12.2
Printer: Officejet-Pro-L7700
Created at: Fri Sep 28 14:12:53 2012
Printed at: Fri Sep 28 14:12:53 2012
```

How do I fix this so the page doesn't print?

Comment: What program are you printing the images from?

Comment: Any program. Firefox, Google Chrome, Image Viewer. If it's an image, that extra page prints.

Comment: Having the same problem with Brother HL 5250-DN, printing from CorelDraW in a KVM-virtualized Windows XP, via IPP/CUPS.

Answer (score 2):

Had this problem too, specifically with the PDF printing... With the latest HPLIP from http://hplipopensource.com/hplip-web/downloads.html and from the Evince: File --> Print --> "Job" tab --> for 'Add Cover Page' --> set 'Before:' to 'None' and 'After:' to 'None'. For some reason mine was set to print 'Secret' under the drop-down arrow choices. Despite all the tips on disabling that "Banner Page" option, the latter one wasn't affecting "print job" 'garbage' output. Hopefully, it will help someone. Cheers!